# HTTPS Post URL with an Array of Objects

Tags: arrays, json, object, post, https

I've been trying to format a URL POST with objects in my array as they're required to post to my REST API. I'm forced to use an archaic API POST system from a vendor and have been trying to hack together a solution.

Basically the JSON looks similar to:

```
{"api_key": "12234", 
"server_id:"qwp2222",
"recipients": [
{"email":"john@doe.com", 
"name": "john doe"}]
}
```

I am trying to format the Array'd key-value pairs as part of the URL so it would post to the endpoint without much fanfare. 
I have the rest of the URL together without issue, it is just the recipients' array that is the problem.

How should I write the POST URL in order to make sure that I can post the array of objects correctly?

I appreciate all the help in advance!

Comment: Would tell there are at least simple 2 options - generate form (DOM) from JSON and submit or generate URL string from JSON ?

Comment: I am attempting to generate the URL string from the JSON so it fits a URL to post to my endpoint. Its a standard REST API but requires the "recipients" portion of the code to be an array of objects (or at the very least thats the error I get back).

Answer (score 0):

Does not work here, but this code will make linear structure from your JSON, create form from and submit to itself.

If you run it on local or anywhere else and add f.action = 'your get or post page', it will send data properly.

```js
var data = {
  api_key: '12234',
  server_id: 'qwp2222',
  recipients: [{
    email: 'john@doe.com',
    name: 'john doe'
  }]
};

function collectItems(res, json) {
  for (var a in json) {
    if (json[a].constructor === Array ||
      json[a].constructor === Object) {
      collectItems(res, json[a]);
    } else {
      res.push([a, json[a]]);
    }
  }
}
var all = [];
collectItems(all, data);
var f = document.createElement('FORM');
f.method = 'post';
// default get: ...?api_key=12234&server_id=qwp2222&email=john@doe.com&name=john+doe
for (var e in all) {
  var i = document.createElement('INPUT');
  i.name = all[e][0];
  i.value = all[e][1];
  i.type = 'hidden'; // do not show values sent
  f.appendChild(i);
}
if (location.search) {
  alert("Submit result:" & location.href);
} else {
  document.body.appendChild(f);
  f.submit();
}
```